# Couldn't find Tray with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating a garden app that has trays and plants.
tray has_many plants, plant belongs_to tray etc.

Im getting the above error and Im not sure how to assign the tray_id to the new plant being created.

Here is the add plant button in my tray's show view

```
<%= link_to 'ADD PLANT', new_plant_path(@tray.id), class: "btn btn-raised btn-success hoverable" %>
```

Here is my plants_controller:

```
class PlantsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_plant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


# GET /plants
# GET /plants.json
def index
  @plants = Plant.all
end


def show
end

def new
  @plant = Plant.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  tray = Tray.find(params[:tray_id])
  @plant = tray.plants.create(plant_params)


  respond_to do |format|
    if @plant.save
      format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @plant }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @plant.update(plant_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @plant }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
def destroy
  @plant.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to plants_url, notice: 'Plant was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.


def set_plant
  @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
end

def plant_params
  params.require(:plant).permit(:title, :notes, :category_id, :tray_id, images_files: [])
  end
end
```

Here is my trays controller

```
class PlantsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_plant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  @plants = Plant.all
end

def show
end

def new
  @plant = Plant.new
end

def edit
end

def create
  tray = Tray.find(params[:tray_id])
  @plant = tray.plants.create(plant_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @plant.save
      format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @plant }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @plant.update(plant_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @plant }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @plant.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to plants_url, notice: 'Plant was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.


  def set_plant
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
  end


  def plant_params
    params.require(:plant).permit(:title, :notes, :category_id, :tray_id, images_files: [])
  end
end
```

Here is my form for creating new plants

```
<%= form_for(@plant) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'NAME' %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', id: 'focusedInput1', placeholder: 'ENTER NAME' %>
 etc, etc
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `params[:tray_id]` is `nil` on this line `tray = Tray.find(params[:tray_id])` in your Posts controller.

You're also not passing `tray_id` anywhere in your params. You'll need to properly pass it as a param to your new action:

```
<%= link_to 'ADD PLANT', new_plant_path(tray_id: @tray.id), class: "btn btn-raised btn-success hoverable" %>
```

Then add a hidden field to pass `:tray_id` in your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :tray_id, value: params[:tray_id] %>
```

Now, you can find tray in your create action using `tray = Tray.find(params[:plant][:tray_id])`.

Comment: Awesome, now its working great.  Thanks for the answer.  Many millions of Karma for you sir :)

Comment: Glad to hear, best of luck!

Comment: Is this the best way to find the attribute of the assigned tray (title is my example here)

Tray.find_by(plant.tray_id).title

Comment: That syntax wont work. You would need to do `Tray.find_by(id: plant.tray_id).title` or `Tray.find(plant.tray_id).title` if you want to throw an exception if a tray with id == plant.tray_id doesn't exist.